# quickstart hue ui potential misconfiguration detected

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

I need help with Hue quickstart, i'm a beginner and i'm facing an issue with opening hue ui.

> Configuration files located in /etc/hue/conf.empty

> Potential misconfiguration detected. Fix and restart Hue.

> hadoop.hdfs_clusters.default.webhdfs_url   Current value: http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1

> Failed to create temporary file "/tmp/hue_config_validation.9845984781315522608"
> Hive Editor The application won't work without a running HiveServer2.

[Here's a snapshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWHS5.png)

**Note**
i tried some commands for restarting hue service but no use

```
sudo service hue stop
sudo service hbase-thrift stop
sudo service hbase-thrift start
sudo service hive-server2 stop
sudo service hive-server2 start
sudo service hue start
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hue but I think this is the relevant log output you should be focusing on "The application won't work without a running HiveServer2". Are you running HiveServer2?

Comment: Is the HDFS NameNode up too? `Failed to create temporary file ` As if it is not, HiveServer2 won't start.